# Severe error in Openerp 6.1

Tags: python, odoo

I have this problem with openerp 6.1, is it possible to repair it? I can't login to the system. This is the error. Thanks for your collaborations

```
>Client Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/openerp/servercp/openerp/addons/web/common/http.py", line 180, in dispatch
     response["result"] = method(controller, self, **self.params)
      File "/opt/openerp/servercp/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 353, in get_list
    dbs = proxy.list()
     File "/opt/openerp/servercp/openerp/addons/web/common/openerplib/main.py", line 117, in proxy
    result = self.connector.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
     File "/opt/openerp/servercp/openerp/addons/web/common/http.py", line 611, in send
    raise fault


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/opt/openerp/servercp/openerp/addons/web/common/http.py", line 592, in send
    result = openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
     File "/opt/openerp/servercp/openerp/netsvc.py", line 360, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
     File "/opt/openerp/servercp/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 117, in dispatch
    return fn(*params)
     File "/opt/openerp/servercp/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 310, in exp_list
    cr = db.cursor()
     File "/opt/openerp/servercp/openerp/sql_db.py", line 465, in cursor
    return Cursor(self._pool, self.dbname, serialized=serialized)
     File "/opt/openerp/servercp/openerp/sql_db.py", line 173, in __init__
    self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn(dbname))
     File "/opt/openerp/servercp/openerp/sql_db.py", line 366, in _locked 
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
     File "/opt/openerp/servercp/openerp/sql_db.py", line 421, in borrow
    result = psycopg2.connect(dsn=dsn, connection_factory=PsycoConnection)
     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
OperationalError: could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory

could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory
could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a postgresql error, it usually happens when the system runs out of memory. If you do not have root access to the machine, you'll need to contact the system administrator